# ImageMagick Bug Stroke overlaying main text after certain character

Tags: php, imagemagick

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz6pv.png)I encountered a problem using ImageMagick.

After typing a tenth or eleventh character, Stroke effect goes back to the beggining of text and overlays previous characters. You can see the bug here https://i.stack.imgur.com/reK8m.jpg

version of ImageMagick is 6.8.9-9

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not the place for (incomplete) bug reports. Consider reporting it on the ImageMagick website.

Comment: I do not think we can speculate on a solution unless you provide your exact command line. It could also be a bug in IM 6.8.9-9. That is 100 versions old. So you might consider upgrading and trying again.